# Stack Overflow interface looks weird?

Tags: support, mobile-web

[image: http://imgur.com/K62H4Ta]

My interface looks like this only in Chrome on my Mac, looks ok everywhere else. Is there some setting I've messed up here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the mobile site. Try reseting browsers: cookies, history, etc. That should do it.

Comment: Or simply clicking on the "full site" link on the footer to get back?

Comment: Or simply scroll to the bottom of the page and click on *full site*.

Comment: Thanks very much, probably hit mobile accidentally with a vimium keybinding and never figured it out.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably emulating a mobile user-agent. Here's documentation from Google on how to enable/disable emulation.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation